# String objects is immutable; why I was able to change it?

Tags: java

I know that String are immutable and once created they cannot change their values.
If so, please guide me to understand what is "wrong" with my code as apparently I was able to change the value of the initial String.
Thanks in advance

```java
package ocajp;

public class TStatic1 {
    
    static String s1 = "Ann";
    static void change() {  s1 += " has apples";}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        change();
        System.out.println("s1: " + s1);
    }
}
```

s1: Ann has apples

Comment: You are creating a new String object and assigning it to the reference s1.

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between objects and references: objects of type `String` are immutable. However, the variable `s1` is a *reference* to an object of type `String`.

What your code does is create a *new string* via concatenation, and then modify the reference `s1` to refer to this newly created string.

Comment: you're right @Konrad Rudolf, this new one confirms it. Thank you  package ocajp;

public class TStatic1 {

 static String s1 = new String("Ann");
 static String change(String input) { 
  input += " has apples";
  return input;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  change(s1);
  System.out.println("s1: " + s1);
 }
}

//brings: 
//s1: Ann

Answer (score 1):

You actually created new object for `s1` variable same as If you did `String newString = s1 + " has apples"`.

And original s1 variable is referenced to this newly created String object